# Access Crashes on Command Execute That Works

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, stored-procedures

I am using an MS Access app as front end to the SQL Server my field staff feed data to via PowerApps.

The MS Access app is rather large and been a labour of love for years and years.  However in September last year I rewrote the front end using a combined approach of SQL stored procedures and some Access codes all based around ADO.

Right now I have a most peculiar issue.

In MS Access I have a procedure CssDirect to which I pass the form name, a number identifying the select case to choose and any ID numbers I need for the relevant SP.  This code hasn't changed and is working elsewhere through out the app.

From the form:

```
 Call cssDirect(12, 1, Me.Form)
 Call cssCheckFormControls(Me.Form)

 With Me.fsubOrderDetail

   Call cssDirect(13, 2, Me.fsubOrderDetail.Form)

   .LinkChildFields = "OrderID"
   .LinkMasterFields = "OrderID"

    'Me.fsubOrderDetail2.SourceObject = "fsubOrderDetailProd"

    Call cssDirect(13, 1, Me.fsubOrderDetail2.Form)

    Me.fsubOrderDetail2.LinkChildFields = "OrderID"
    Me.fsubOrderDetail2.LinkMasterFields = "OrderID"


End With
```

The form code runs fine.

Extract from the Module:

```
Public Sub cssDirect(intI As Integer, id As Long, frm As Form)

Select Case intI

Case Is = 1 'Client

    Call cssLoad("EXEC mysp_ClientSearch " & Nz(id), frm)

Case Is = 2 'Site

Code Removed to make shorter

Case Is = 13

    Call cssLoad("EXEC mysp_OrderDetail " & Nz(id), frm)


End Select
```

This procedure calls the cssLoad which is the code to handle the command text.  Fairly simple:

```
Public Sub cssLoad(strCommand As String, frm As Form)

Dim com As New ADODB.Command


 If gcn.State = 0 Then Call cssOpenConnection


With com


Set .ActiveConnection = gcn
.CommandType = adCmdText
.CommandText = strCommand 'Runs sp with parameter

Debug.Print strCommand
Debug.Print frm.Name

Set frm.Recordset = .Execute



End With


End Sub
```

This code has been great.  Just does what it says on the box until this morning.

Today for Call cssLoad("EXEC mysp_OrderDetail " & Nz(id), frm) the MS Access front end is shutting down completely on line Set frm.Recordset = .Execute in cssLoad.

This has never happened before.  I have run the SP direct and it runs fine and is working correctly.

Below is a script extract from the SQL server.  If you want to play along.  I have not included confidential information but I think there is enough there to follow along.

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Order]    Script Date: 17/06/2020 5:22:22 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Order](
    [OrderID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AdminID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [JobID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SupplierID] [int] NULL,
    [PlacedBy] [int] NULL,
    [OrderDate] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [PONumber] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [RequiredDate] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [DeliveryID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Freight] [money] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Order] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [OrderID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[OrderDetail]    Script Date: 17/06/2020 5:22:22 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrderDetail](
    [OrderDetailID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [OrderID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Quantity] [numeric](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [ProductSource] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProductID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UnitPrice] [decimal](28, 4) NULL,
    [DiscountAsPercent] [numeric](18, 4) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_OrderDetail] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [OrderDetailID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[ProductSource]    Script Date: 17/06/2020 5:22:22 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductSource](
    [PSID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProductSource] [nchar](20) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ProductSource] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PSID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Order] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[Order] ([OrderID], [AdminID], [JobID], [SupplierID], [PlacedBy], [OrderDate], [PONumber], [RequiredDate], [DeliveryID], [Freight]) VALUES (11, 1, 155, 17, NULL, CAST(N'2020-06-08T00:00:00' AS SmallDateTime), CAST(123456 AS Numeric(18, 0)), CAST(N'2020-06-11T00:00:00' AS SmallDateTime), 3, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[Order] ([OrderID], [AdminID], [JobID], [SupplierID], [PlacedBy], [OrderDate], [PONumber], [RequiredDate], [DeliveryID], [Freight]) VALUES (12, 1, 162, 32, NULL, CAST(N'2020-06-08T00:00:00' AS SmallDateTime), CAST(1 AS Numeric(18, 0)), CAST(N'2020-06-11T00:00:00' AS SmallDateTime), 1, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[Order] ([OrderID], [AdminID], [JobID], [SupplierID], [PlacedBy], [OrderDate], [PONumber], [RequiredDate], [DeliveryID], [Freight]) VALUES (25, 1, 195, 17, NULL, CAST(N'2020-06-09T00:00:00' AS SmallDateTime), CAST(13546 AS Numeric(18, 0)), CAST(N'2020-06-12T00:00:00' AS SmallDateTime), 6, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[Order] ([OrderID], [AdminID], [JobID], [SupplierID], [PlacedBy], [OrderDate], [PONumber], [RequiredDate], [DeliveryID], [Freight]) VALUES (30, 1, 182, 44, NULL, CAST(N'2020-06-09T00:00:00' AS SmallDateTime), CAST(1 AS Numeric(18, 0)), CAST(N'2020-06-12T00:00:00' AS SmallDateTime), 6, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[Order] ([OrderID], [AdminID], [JobID], [SupplierID], [PlacedBy], [OrderDate], [PONumber], [RequiredDate], [DeliveryID], [Freight]) VALUES (31, 1, 181, 17, NULL, CAST(N'2020-06-12T00:00:00' AS SmallDateTime), CAST(123456 AS Numeric(18, 0)), CAST(N'2020-06-15T00:00:00' AS SmallDateTime), 6, NULL)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Order] OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[OrderDetail] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[OrderDetail] ([OrderDetailID], [OrderID], [Quantity], [ProductSource], [ProductID], [UnitPrice], [DiscountAsPercent]) VALUES (30, 12, CAST(5.00 AS Numeric(18, 2)), 1, 1199, CAST(2333.2500 AS Decimal(28, 4)), NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[OrderDetail] ([OrderDetailID], [OrderID], [Quantity], [ProductSource], [ProductID], [UnitPrice], [DiscountAsPercent]) VALUES (31, 25, CAST(1.00 AS Numeric(18, 2)), 1, 833, CAST(104.5000 AS Decimal(28, 4)), NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[OrderDetail] ([OrderDetailID], [OrderID], [Quantity], [ProductSource], [ProductID], [UnitPrice], [DiscountAsPercent]) VALUES (32, 25, CAST(15.00 AS Numeric(18, 2)), 2, 457, CAST(8.8000 AS Decimal(28, 4)), NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[OrderDetail] ([OrderDetailID], [OrderID], [Quantity], [ProductSource], [ProductID], [UnitPrice], [DiscountAsPercent]) VALUES (33, 25, CAST(10.00 AS Numeric(18, 2)), 2, 462, CAST(21.5000 AS Decimal(28, 4)), NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[OrderDetail] ([OrderDetailID], [OrderID], [Quantity], [ProductSource], [ProductID], [UnitPrice], [DiscountAsPercent]) VALUES (40, 31, CAST(1.00 AS Numeric(18, 2)), 2, 466, CAST(47.5000 AS Decimal(28, 4)), CAST(0.0000 AS Numeric(18, 4)))
INSERT [dbo].[OrderDetail] ([OrderDetailID], [OrderID], [Quantity], [ProductSource], [ProductID], [UnitPrice], [DiscountAsPercent]) VALUES (44, 11, CAST(2.00 AS Numeric(18, 2)), 2, 1223, CAST(221.0000 AS Decimal(28, 4)), NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[OrderDetail] ([OrderDetailID], [OrderID], [Quantity], [ProductSource], [ProductID], [UnitPrice], [DiscountAsPercent]) VALUES (50, 30, CAST(1.00 AS Numeric(18, 2)), 2, 456, CAST(0.0000 AS Decimal(28, 4)), NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[OrderDetail] ([OrderDetailID], [OrderID], [Quantity], [ProductSource], [ProductID], [UnitPrice], [DiscountAsPercent]) VALUES (51, 11, CAST(1.00 AS Numeric(18, 2)), 1, 1218, CAST(436.3100 AS Decimal(28, 4)), NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[OrderDetail] ([OrderDetailID], [OrderID], [Quantity], [ProductSource], [ProductID], [UnitPrice], [DiscountAsPercent]) VALUES (52, 31, CAST(1.00 AS Numeric(18, 2)), 1, 1178, CAST(20.1000 AS Decimal(28, 4)), NULL)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[OrderDetail] OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[ProductSource] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[ProductSource] ([PSID], [ProductSource]) VALUES (1, N'Product             ')
INSERT [dbo].[ProductSource] ([PSID], [ProductSource]) VALUES (2, N'ShentonStock        ')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[ProductSource] OFF
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Order]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Order_Admin] FOREIGN KEY([AdminID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Admin] ([AdminID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Order] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Order_Admin]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Order]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Order_DeliveryLocation] FOREIGN KEY([DeliveryID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[DeliveryLocation] ([DeliveryID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Order] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Order_DeliveryLocation]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Order]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Order_Job] FOREIGN KEY([JobID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Job] ([JobID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Order] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Order_Job]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Order]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Order_Supplier] FOREIGN KEY([SupplierID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Supplier] ([SupplierID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Order] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Order_Supplier]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OrderDetail]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_OrderDetail_Order] FOREIGN KEY([OrderID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Order] ([OrderID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OrderDetail] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_OrderDetail_Order]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OrderDetail]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_OrderDetail_ProductSource] FOREIGN KEY([ProductSource])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ProductSource] ([PSID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OrderDetail] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_OrderDetail_ProductSource]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProductSource]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ProductSource_ProductSource] FOREIGN KEY([PSID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ProductSource] ([PSID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProductSource] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ProductSource_ProductSource]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[mysp_OrderDetail]    Script Date: 17/06/2020 5:22:25 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      David Watson
-- Create date: 17/06/2020
-- Description: Get the subform orderdetails data
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[mysp_OrderDetail] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @ProductSourceID int = 0,
    @OrderID int = 0
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here

    if @OrderID=0

    SELECT        OrderDetailID, OrderID, Quantity, ProductSource, ProductID, UnitPrice, DiscountAsPercent
    FROM            dbo.OrderDetail
    WHERE         ProductSource=@ProductSourceID

    ELSE

    SELECT        OrderDetailID, OrderID, Quantity, ProductSource, ProductID, UnitPrice, DiscountAsPercent
    FROM            dbo.OrderDetail
    WHERE         ProductSource=@ProductSourceID AND  OrderID = @OrderID

END
GO
```

I cant see any reason for this to fail.  I thought it may be because the form is a sub form, however I do this elsewhere reliably and have ticked off all the properties between a working form and the two that are not working.

I am going nuts.  Anyone got any other ideas on what I may be able to try?

Comment: One of gcn or frm is null or disposed? Probably gcn or I'd expect it to die on Debug.Print frm.Name.

Comment: I actually only wanted to vote to close... but I'm fairly certain that the new bug in Access is the issue. DECIMAL + DAO leads to the crash.